# Abstract database implementation in C++

Tags: c++

I wanna create abstract Db class and implement Pg (postgresql) by inheriting from Db:

**Db.h**:

```
template <class T>
class Db 
{
public:
    Db(std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string);
    virtual ~Db();

protected:
    T* getConnection();
    std::string getHost();
    std::string getUsername();
    std::string getDatabase();
    std::string getPassword();
    virtual std::string getConnectionString()=0;

private: 
    T* connection;
    std::string host;
    std::string username;
    std::string database;
    std::string password;
};
```

**Db.cpp**:

```
#include "Db.h"

using namespace std;

template <class T>
Db<T>::Db(string iHost, string iUsername, string iDatabase, string iPassword) 
    : host(iHost), username(iUsername), database(iDatabase), password(iPassword) {
    T* conn(getConnectionString());
    connection = conn;
}

template <class T>
T* Db<T>::getConnection() {
    return connection;
}

... getters
```

**Pg.h**:

```
#include "../Db.h"

template <class T>
class Pg : public Db<T> {
public:
    virtual std::string getConnectionString();
};
```

**Pg.cpp**:

```
#include "Pg.h"

template <class T>
std::string Pg<T>::getConnectionString() {
    return "host=" + this->getHost() + " user=" + this->getUsername() 
        + " password=" + this->getPassword() + " dbname=" + this->getDatabase();
}
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/connection>
#include <pqxx/transaction>
#include "lib/db/pg/Pg.h"

using namespace std;

int main () {
    string host     = "localhost";
    string username = "username";
    string database = "db";
    string password = "root";

    try {
        Pg<pqxx::connection> *db(host, username, database, password);
    } catch (pqxx::broken_connection) {
        cout << "Failed to establish connection." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for long implementation. After compiling with g++ I get an error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:15:62: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
   Pg<pqxx::connection> *db(host, username, database, password);
                                                              ^
main.cpp:15:62: error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘Pg<pqxx::basic_connection<pqxx::connect_direct> >*’ in initialization
```

I don't know if it is a good idea in the end, because my first version with only main() function looked more compact. I just try to hide connection details somewhere, such as connection string.

Comment: It was my first version, In case if the pointer sign is not specified I get another error: **error: no matching function for call to ‘Pg<pqxx::basic_connection<pqxx::connect_direct> >::Pg(std::string&, std::string&, std::string&, std::string&)’**

Comment: You should make a MINIMAL REPRODUCIBLE example.  Remove try-catch block, and check if the error is still here.  Remove Db.cpp and Pg.cpp, and check if the error is still here.  Try Pg<int> instead of Pg<pgxx::connection>.  Remove parameters and member functions of Db.h . Remove everything you can, as long as the syntax error is reproducable, then make one bigger file instead of several smaller files, then send your code here.

Answer (score 0):

In `main()`, your `db` variable is declared as a pointer.  You cannot pass constructor parameters to a pointer like you are doing.

You need to either:

1. drop the `*` from the declaration:

   ```
   Pg<pqxx::connection> db(host, username, database, password);
   ```
2. keep the `*` and use `new` to construct the object:

   ```
   Pg<pqxx::connection> *db = new Pg<pqxx::connection>(host, username, database, password);
   ...
   delete db;
   ```